# Partial Views in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, dynamic, laravel-blade

I am a beginner in using CodeIgniter Framework. Previously, I have learned Laravel. and my problem is I want to make dynamic template like Blade in Laravel. So, in every pages I just load the style and script that only needed by that page.

Here is the code, that I created with CodeIgniter so It could be dynamic to load custom style and custom script.

template.php

```
 <?php
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

        // <hmtl>
        $this->load->view($header);
        if(isset($style))
            $this->load->view($style);

        // <body>
        $this->load->view($navbar);
        if(isset($sidebar))
            $this->load->view($sidebar);
        $this->load->view($content);
        $this->load->view($footer);
        // </body>

        if(isset($script))
            $this->load->view($script);
        // </html>
```

and my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'title'     => 'Home',
            'header'    => 'partials/_header',
            'navbar'    => 'partials/_navbar',
            'content'   => 'guest/public',
            'footer'    => 'partials/_footer'
        ];
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
```

maybe you have better thought, because I am stuck with it. in Laravel it's easy because there is `@yield` and `@section`.
 any ideas from you guys, would be so helpful to me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally, I just figured it out the best way make it dynamic. how to load custom script and css in every different pages.

here is the code for template.php (inside views folder)

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    $this->load->view($header);
    $this->load->view($navbar);
    $this->load->view($content);
    $this->load->view($footer);
```

and the controller controller

```
public function index() {
    $data = [
        'header'        => 'partials/_header',
        'style'         => 'partials/style/_public_css',
        'navbar'        => 'partials/_navbar',
        'content'       => 'guest/public',
        'footer'        => 'partials/_footer',
        'script'        => 'partials/script/_public_js'
    ];
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

and in the partials view of _header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>...</title>

   <!-- Partial CSS Here -->
   <?php if(isset($style)) $this->load->view($style); ?>
</head>
<body>
```

_navbar.php

```
<header>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      ....
   </nav>
</header>
```

then the content variable in controller, it loads public.php (in my case, you have to replace with any pages you want to load)

```
<div class="container">
     ....
</div>
```

and the last one is _footer.php

```
    <footer>
         ....
    </footer>

    <!-- JQuery HERE -->

    <!-- any js that you will you in all pages HERE -->

    <!-- Partial Script Here -->
    <?php if(isset($script)) $this->load->view($script); ?>
</body>
<html>
```

**Remember**, if your footer does static in every pages place your JQuery in _footer.php and if it doesn't just place the jquery in the _header.php even it's not the best practice to load the script first.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar once, sometime ago admittedly now, but I did it all in a template library.

Using setters like

```
   $this->template_library->set_css_script('page.css');
   $this->template_library->set_layout('product_page');
```

The controller would end with a call like:

```
  $this->template_library->render_page();
```

The template library would then use the load->view functions to create the page and output it depending on the values that were set or not set, and the page layout meant I could have various set layouts like home_page, product_page, checkout_page, message_page etc etc.

For the layouts, I had one master layout that did the main page, and variations for the different pages.

In the end though I reverted to simple views, with common files for header and footer and any variants. It was just easier to maintain lots of different view files than it was to maintain all the layouts and templates and partials.

One thing that helps a lot is that a view can load another view. So for the sake of keeping everything DRY, this means that any derivative page part views can be kept in a 'partials' folder for things like 'related products' or 'blog_list' etc.

Hope that helps.